# How to use Fuse android location provider in a service?

Tags: android, service, android-fusedlocation

I am trying to use Fuse provider in a service in android to get location in background.

```
  private void init() {
    context = this;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            // location is received
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            showLocation();
        }
    };

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
}

   private void startLocationUpdates() {
    mSettingsClient
            .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
     =====>>>>       .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Started location updates!");
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

                     showLocation();
                }
            })
    =====>>>>        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
}
```

in service i can not use "this" because it refer to an activity.

I want to know how to implement this code in service?

Answer (score 0):

I have change it to this, and worked...

```
    private void init() {
    context = this;
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            // location is received
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

            showLocation();
        }
    };

    mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }



     private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mSettingsClient
                .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
         =====>>>>       .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Started location updates!");
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

                     showLocation();
                }
            })
    =====>>>>        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
}
```